# Send email to alternative email addresses on each form submission

Tags: php, forms, joomla, form-submit

I am working on a form submission on RSForm where is need to send an email to alternative email addresses on each alternative submission for example.

```
Submission 1 = Email A
Submission 2 = Email B
Submission 3 = Email A
Submission 4 = Email B
Submission 5 = Email C
```

So here if the submission is no 1 the email should go to Email A and so on.
Is there any way to track or maintain which submission number is the current one with the help of javascript or PHP? Is there a way to maintain this on Joomla's Form?

Comment: Is this supposed to be per-user? Or global? Does it happen over the course of minutes? Or months? Anyway, I'd put a serialized array of the addresses in the DB table. When the email is going to get sent, I load the array, send to the first email address, move it to the back of the array and store the array back in the DB.

Comment: This is going to be global and I need to send email to alternative email addresses on each submission. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, exactly like I described. However you need a way to insert completely custom code into Joomla!. No idea how to do that (I'm just here because you've mistakenly tagged this JavaScript)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.. sorry i tagged it with javascript

Comment: No problem; people add irrelevant tags all the time ;)

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there to receive support from people with an intimate understanding of the CMS and its extensions.